# Controller Method Not Found Strange Behaviour

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, request-validation

I have an AuthController in my laravel app, inside that controller i have several methods:

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
{
  ...
}

public function getRegister()
{
  ...
}

public function postRegister(RegisterRequest $request)
{
  ...
}
```

For some reason now my `postRegister()` function does not work, when I run it in postman for some reason it always executes `getRegister()` instead, when i take out `getRegister()` it says Controller method not found.

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v1/', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Auth\Controllers'], function() {
    /**
     * Authentication
     */
    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'AuthController',
        'password' => 'PasswordController',
    ]);
});
```

**Edit:** I have narrowed the issue down to my request file, the path is correct but for some reason when i try to use it in postRegister(RegisterRequest $request), the postRegister function does not get executed, no errors are thrown, it worked before now i have no idea what is causing this issue now.

I think i should also add that i created custom namespaces which i am using in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and changing my code i found a solution here:
[laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-custom-request-not-working](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-custom-request-not-working)

Apparently when using postman to test your APIs in laravel you need to set the `AcceptHeader` to `Application/json`.  I did not know this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in Postman you are setting the HTTP method to 'POST', you are probably using 'GET' which is hitting the 'get' route not the 'post' route.

You can do a `php artisan route:list` to see your actual routes and the HTTP method(s) they accept.

Comment: No i am most definitely using a POST the reason why i even tested it in postman was because it was not working in my application.  Unless postman secretly uses GET when i select POST.

Comment: what url are you posting to ?

Comment: It's on my local host.

Comment: yea got it, what url on your localhost are you trying to post to ?

Comment: However when i take out RegisterRequest $request it works, it actually points to postRegister() but when i put it back it points to getRegister().